# how to convert DateDiff back to datetime?

Tags: sql-server

datediff(second,@date1, @date2)

i.e.  exact difference between 2004-09-01 09:56:11.000 and 2005-02-02 08:54:02.000...output should be 5 months, x days, y hours,z minutes, m seconds.

Comment: How would you relate seconds to a `datetime` datatype? With the year 0000? Does that make sense? You could do it with a `dateadd` btw.

Comment: I want the exact difference between 2004-09-01 09:56:11.000 and 
2005-02-02 08:54:02.000...output should be 5 months, x days, y hours,z minutes,  m seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way more difficult than I originally thought, Calculating months and days is complicated. Here is an attempt. You should test it carefully, I imagine leapyear could also cause problems for the year calculation, so I removed it from the answer since it is not part of your question:

```
DECLARE @date1 datetime = '2004-09-01 09:56:11.000',
        @date2 datetime = '2005-02-02 08:54:02.000'

SELECT 
  @date2 - @date1 difference,
  datediff(month, @date1, @date2) + 
    CASE WHEN dateadd(month, datediff(month, @date1, @date2), @date1)>@date2 
    THEN -1
    ELSE 0 END month, 
  day(@date2 - dateadd(month, datediff(month, @date1, @date2) 
    + CASE WHEN dateadd(month, datediff(month, @date1, @date2), @date1)>@date2
      THEN -1 ELSE 0 
      END, @date1)) - 1 day,
  datepart(hour,@date2 - @date1) hour,
  datepart(minute,@date2 - @date1) minute,
  datepart(second,@date2 - @date1) second
```

Result now:

```
difference                month  day  hour  minute  second
1900-06-03 22:57:51.000       5    0    22      57      51
```

Note: This answer will not give you exactly the same result, but it will be more accurate with seconds being rounded down.

More edit:

If you can accept not having the months as described in your comment and can accept this format x days hh:MM:ss. You can use this syntax:

```
SELECT 
  CAST((DateDiff(SECOND, @date1, @date2)) / 86400 AS varchar(7)) + ' days ' 
  + CAST(cast(@date2 - @date1 as time(0)) as char(8))
```

Comment: 2004-09-01 09:56:11.000 and 2005-02-02 08:54:02.000...i want the result to be 5 months, x days, y hours,z minutes, m seconds.

Comment: @ParulSingla I had corrected query and not result. Both are updated now

Comment: going to rewrite the calculating for this, like the other answers It will not be 100 % exact for months

Comment: I am sorry i calculated wrong difference. the actual time diff is   153 days, 22 hours, 57 minutes and 51 seconds. or 5 months 22 hours, 57 minutes and 51 seconds. it shows 2 days. but it should be 0.

Comment: @ParulSingla that i can believe, same issue as month, the days are left over when months are subtracted. Working on a solution

Comment: ,left('0' + CAST((dATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.owndate, mp.owndate)) / 86400 AS VARCHAR),2) + ' days ' +
left('0' + CAST((dATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.owndate, mp.owndate)) / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
right('0' + CAST(((dATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.owndate, mp.owndate)) / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
right('0' + CAST((dATEDIFF(SECOND, mc.owndate, mp.owndate)) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)   .. can we use something like this?

Comment: @ParulSingla removed some of my comments and improved my answer

Answer (score 3):

You need that as hours and minutes? You can use dateadd to 0 date:

```
dateadd(second, amount, 0)
```

And then convert this into suitable format using convert and the formatting options like 108.

```
convert(varchar, dateadd(second, amount, 0), 108)
```

Comment: Yes this works only for smaller units of time, which I assumed was the case when measuring in seconds since at that time the question didn't mention days or months.

Answer (score 0):

`datediff` has 3 parameters, not 2: `datediff(daypart, startdate, enddate)`. If you need difference in seconds, use `datediff(second, @date1, @date2)`.
To convert it back to datetime, use `dateadd(datepart, number, startdate)`. E.g. `dateadd(second, @diffResult, '1900-01-01')`. For start date choose one that fits your needs.